# Python: Parse a log file with logger regex and store to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex, parsing, logging

Im trying to parse a log file with regex, but im not getting lucky to get the data in a appropriate way. So far i only got the "timestamp" only.

This is the raw log file data sample

```
190.183.122.215 - - [19/Mar/2023:16:17:01 -0300] "PROPFIND /mauricio HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.21996"
87.236.176.50 - - [19/Mar/2023:16:51:24 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; InternetMeasurement/1.0; +https://internet-measurement.com/)"
168.119.63.138 - - [20/Mar/2023:21:06:34 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 162 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"
```

And this is my try to parse te logs

```
reg = r'(?P<IP>[^-])- -(?P<Timestamp>[^]]+)' 

for e in logger.parse("access_log_edw.processed", reg):
    print(e)
```

And the result:

```
{'IP': ' ', 'Timestamp': ' [19/Mar/2023:16:17:01 -0300'}
{'IP': ' ', 'Timestamp': ' [19/Mar/2023:16:51:24 -0300'}
{'IP': ' ', 'Timestamp': ' [20/Mar/2023:21:06:34 -0300'}
```

The main idea is to parse the information to a dataframe. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(list(logger.parse(...))`?

Comment: I wouldn't include the spaces. With the IP think you forgot to add + to allow more than one character (that's why only the space before `-` is included). Suggestion: `^(?P<IP>[^ ]+) - - \[(?P<Timestamp>[^]]+)`

Comment: @Jay This actually works, but im currently getting the first row only. I am learning regex, so maybe could be my mistake.

Comment: @MauricioGoette Try using `re.M` for multiline.